# Selenium stops when browser is manually interrupted

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When Selenium starts it opens the browser and starts to fill the data, but when the user clicks somewhere in the browser while the `selenium` is running, then selenium execution stops, which crashes my application, is it possible to handle such crashes

Comment: What is error or the console output you see in logs?

Comment: Why is someone clicking the browser while Selenium is running?

Answer (score 4):

When you use [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to execute your program/script, **Selenium** needs the **focus** on the *Browser Client* which renders the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

Now, when the *test execution* is *In Progress* if an user manually clicks somewhere withinin the browser, *Selenium* looses the **focus** and an **exception** will be raised.

Comment: If you use two monitor, then the case is different. While you use two monitor and if you use firefox brower, one monitor you can allow your automation and in another monitor you can continue to type something else but if you use chrome, then it's not possible because chrome needs the focus , so it pull the control from you.

Comment: so when selenium runs the user should keep his hands away from the browser right?

Comment: @Grijan Yup, that's right, at the least no manual clicks on the browser session initiated by Selenium.

Comment: Find find many issues when the browser is obstructed by other windows too. Normally when in front it works fine.